# Read More collapse script change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to collapse each "read-more" for its own section. The code is borrowed from w3schools and trying to modify by adding a second section. But the second button expands s the first text. I understand (from reading on other sections) I will have to modify the id for elements so that each section is self-contained. What do I need to modify this behavior?  This is a new area for me, be gentle ...

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>One</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<h2>Two</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Can you give an example? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change all your IDs with classes, for example, 'cause IDs must be unique in a page.

After that, a solution could be to insert the 2 texts in 2 divs, passing `this` element to the `myFunction` to select the right [parent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) box to work on.

```js
function myFunction(elmnt) {
  var myID = elmnt.parentNode;
  
  var dots = myID.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0];
  var moreText = myID.getElementsByClassName("more")[0];
  var btnText = myID.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.more {display: none;}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>One</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**
You have to change all IDs 'cause they must be unique in a page. **You can't use them for another textbox**. So if you want to use 2,3,4... several textboxes, you have to transform all IDs in classes.

In my example, I changed a little the script to manage those classes, not IDs. Copy and paste my code in w3school snippet, click "Run" and you'll see it work. I changed the name of variable `myID` in `parentElement` so maybe it is more clear to you.
The script `var dots = parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0];` means *find first element that has a class named "dots" in my parentElement (i.e. the external div that I added)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <h2>One</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(elmnt) {
  var parentElement = elmnt.parentNode;

  var dots = parentElement.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0];
  var moreText = parentElement.getElementsByClassName("more")[0];
  var btnText = parentElement.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code isn't working for me. I'd appreciate a bit more explanation. Or give me something I can cut/paste so I can try and understand the logic. I am new at this, be gentle....

Comment: Yes, I used your code and and it didn't work.  I manually drew the DOM for both your snippet and the orig using id instead of class to compare. I see the same class group ids on yours, but not sure how it control separate actions with the same id.  I had a work around (not elegant) to make it work -  I added diff id and second function to control  the button. What I don't understand about your code is that you used class to group them, and added a var myID and a [0] at the end of the var definitions. can you give example using diff id and a single function instead of class? Thanks Resedano.

Comment: Here is the code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't know how to be more clear. It's because of my poor english, I think. Try to see if now the answer is more understandable to you. :-)